# how to user only-of-type with not sector in css

Tags: css, sass, less

when just one  .lesson  ignore. when more then one (two or more) .lesson is together. select them.

some of my solution:

1. use .lesson + .lesson, this will not select the first when more than one.
2. :not(.lesson:only-of-type) not work.

html code is below. many thanks.

```html
<ol>
    <li class="chapter">Chapter item 1</li>
    <li class="lesson">Lesson item 1</li>
    <li class="chapter">Chapter item 2</li>
    <li class="lesson">Lesson item 2</li>
    <li class="lesson">Lesson item 3</li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Only-of-type works only for types. Your elements are all of type "li". So only-of-type will not work for your layout

Comment: `:only-child` selector might be helpful

Comment: seems not work. just work for below
```html
<ol>
    <li class="lesson">Chapter item 1</li>
</ol>
```
@anderssonola

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you want to do exactly? So maybe there are other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: @UfguFugullu  I want to distinguish the style  with one `lesson ` and more than two `lesson` . for example, if the first chapter have one `lesson` , the `lesson` color is red , and if the second chapter have two  or more `lesson`, the `lesson` color should be blue. 

hope that you can understand me, and also many thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with your current html and pure CSS.

A solution could it be to rethink your hmtl and put the lessons into a sublist of your chapters. I hope this example will help you:

```css
.chapter-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lessons li:not(:only-child) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="chapter">
    <span class="chapter-title">Chapter item 1</span>
    <ol class="lessons">
      <li>Lesson item 1</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="chapter">
    <span class="chapter-title">Chapter item 2</span>
    <ol class="lessons">
      <li>Lesson item 2</li>
      <li>Lesson item 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```